# Quill Editor switches to RTL language direction when decorated with "ref" property

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, wysiwyg, quill, vue-quill-editor

I've created a `text-editor vue component` with `quill editor` and configured it to display data from a database inside its input field. For that I need the `ref="quill"` property on the `<quill-editor>` element together with a `watcher`. Problem is that as soon as I add the property, the editor switches to `bi-directional` (right-to-left) language direction.

**`text-editor.vue`**:

```html
<template>
  <div id="text-editor" class="text-editor">
    <quill-editor ref="quill" :modules="modules" :toolbar="toolbar" v-model:content="store.re.body" contentType="html"/>
  </div>
</template>


<script setup>
import BlotFormatter from 'quill-blot-formatter'
import store from "../../../js/store";
import {ref, watch} from "vue";

store.re.body = ''

const modules = {
    module: BlotFormatter,
}

const toolbar = [
    [{ 'header': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, false] }],
    [{ 'size': ['small', false, 'large', 'huge'] }],
    ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strike'],
    ['blockquote', 'code-block'],
    [{ 'align': [] }],
    [{ 'list': 'ordered'}, { 'list': 'bullet' }],
    [{ 'color': [] }, { 'background': [] }],
    [{ 'font': [] }],
    ['link', 'image', 'video'],
    ['clean']
];

const quill = ref(null)

watch(() => store.re.body, newValue => quill.value.setHTML(newValue))

</script>
```

[image]

I've tried changing it with `CSS` but it didn't help:

```css
.ql-editor { direction: ltr }
```

The css-property is applied to `quill` but the language direction stays RTL.

Adding `[{ 'direction': 'ltr' }]` to the `toolbar` object does not help either. Any idea how to debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue isn't caused by adding a `ref` to `<quill-editor>`.

This looks like [`vue-quill#52`](https://github.com/vueup/vue-quill/issues/52). The author tried to fix it in [this patch](https://github.com/vueup/vue-quill/commit/f2bf17150ddfe87e8ba6ff80e16fe2602f84fbd4), but that only broke editor updates via `v-model:content`. You used `setHTML()` to workaround that issue, but cursor-reset bug was still active. Then, typing anything would cause text to be prepended, making it only appear to be RTL.

As a workaround, you could move the cursor to the end of the line and re-focus:

```js
watch(
  () => store.re.body,
  newValue => {
    quill.value.setHTML(newValue)

    // Workaround https://github.com/vueup/vue-quill/issues/52
    // move cursor to end
    nextTick(() => {
      let q = quill.value.getQuill()
      q.setSelection(newValue.length, 0, 'api')
      q.focus()
    })
  }
)
```

[demo 1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vue-quill-update-content-znhg3t?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyEditor.vue)

However, this reveals a new problem in that deleting text from the middle of the editor causes the cursor to jump to the end. We need a way to update `store.re.body` and move the cursor **only** when the update is from the `v-model`. Otherwise, the external update (from the other component's fetch) should *not* move the cursor.

You can implement that behavior as follows:

1. Replace the `<quill-editor>`'s `v-model:content` with a new `content` ref.
2. Watch the `content` ref, updating `store.re.body` with the new value. Also track this new value as `newContent`.
3. In the watch on `store.re.body`, ignore the new value if it's equal to `newContent`.

```html
<template>                          1️⃣
  <quill-editor v-model:content="content" ⋯/>
</template>
<script setup>
         1️⃣
const content = ref('')

2️⃣
let newContent = ''
watch(content, newValue => {
  newContent = newValue
  store.re.body = newValue
})

watch(
  () => store.re.body,
  newValue => {
    3️⃣
    if (newContent === newValue) return

    ⋮ /* setHTML() and move cursor to end */
  }
})
</script>
```

[demo 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-vue-quill-update-content-etk8jd?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FMyEditor.vue)

Comment: Thank you for all that insight. Would a downgrade to an earlier build of quill make `v-model` reactively usable?

Comment: Not sure if a downgrade would help. Only way to find out would be to try! :) I would do a `git bisect` to hone in on the bug.